# What signal does the front button of a Wii Board send, to be consumed by a Python script?

Tags: python, bluetooth, bluez, wiimote, wii-balanceboard

I am trying to write a daemon which would listen to incoming messages from a Wii Board and translate them into a weight (and send it further to an existing dashboard). This will heavily reuse some [existing implementations](https://www.stavros.io/posts/your-weight-online/).

I have the [code](https://github.com/skorokithakis/gr8w8upd8m8/blob/master/gr8w8upd8m8.py) from the implementation above working fine when pressing the red synchronization button on the Wii Board (it displays my weight). I now would like to use the front button to synchronize (instead of the red one).

The Wii Board is paired and trusted. When starting the program with the address of the Wii Board and pressing the front button, I get a timeout `bluetooth.btcommon.BluetoothError: (112, 'Host is down')` on

```
self.receivesocket.connect((address, 0x13))
```

I get the same result when not pressing anything. Again, pressing the red button works fine.

I was under the impression that the red button is for pairing and not used after that (this is the behaviour of a Wii). The front button would be usd for initiating the connection then.

Is the failing call above expecting something the Wii Board can send via the front button? In other words - can this button replace the red synchronization one and under which conditions?

*Note: I am aware that this question is borderline SO-compatible. I put it here because I am looking to write/improve a Python daemon but lack the Bluetooth knowledge. If you feel it is better moved somewhere (SU? RPi?) please let me know.*